# How can i overcome an error validating an image input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I am close to completing a task but are stuck on validating 3 fields so at least one field has a value. The first and last fields validate fine. The problem is the type=file input, as the validation doesn't like file[] as the field name. How can I validate the type=file input? Here is my code -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#contact").validate({
        rules: {
            Text: {
                require_from_group: [1, ".form-control"]
            },
            file[]: {
                require_from_group: [1, ".form-control"]
            },
            Video: {
                require_from_group: [1, ".form-control"]
            }
        },

        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            error.appendTo(element.parents ('.formf'));
        }
    });

});
</script>

<form action="post.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="contact" id="contact">      

<div class="formt">text</div>
<div class="formf"><textarea name="Text" class="form-control"></textarea></div>

<div class="formt">image</div>
<div class="formf"><input id="fileInputBox" type="file" name="file[]" class="form-control"/></div>


<div class="formt">video</div>
<div class="formf"><input id="fileInputBox2" type="file" name="Video" class="form-control"/></div>

<div class="formff">
<button type="submit" class="button" id="SubmitButton">splat!</button>
</div>

<div class="formtt">
you submit you agree to piggy's <a href="">terms</a>
</div>

<div class="formff">
<div id="progressbox"><div id="progressbar"></div ><div id="statustxt">0%</div ></div>
</div>


</form>
```

Comment: Try wrapping it in quotes like `"file[]": {`

Comment: perhaps changing the name to something else might work

Comment: This is a FAQ from the docs... http://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/#link-fields-with-complex-names-(brackets-dots)